# Distributing files of a clickonce application

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, clickonce

I did deploy a clickonce application, uploaded the files successfully to the server. I select to check for updates before the application is open.

What I didn't understand well is which files must I distribuite to end-user and to clickonce do its job must I run the `.application` or `steup.exe` (from `app.publish` folder) or my application executable like I would do usually?

it generate a `.application` and a folder called `app.publish` within the release dir. Within `app.publish` there are some files, among them a copy of my application executable (but not the dependent files, like the dlls and such),  `.application` and `setup.exe`. What is each file for?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is list of files and folders:

- **Setup.exe:** It is the installer of your application. If you double click on it, it installs the application. It needs `YourProgramName.application` and `Application Files` to install the application.
- **YourProgramName.application:**  It is the [application manifest file](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ws1c2fch.aspx) that contains information about the  application that is deployed using ClickOnce.  If you double click on it, if you have installed application, runs the application and if you have not installed the application, gets setup.exe and installs the application and then run it.
- **Application Files:** Contains files of different versions of application to deploy. `Setup.exe` needs these files to install the application. All of your application files located under sub folders of `Application Files` with `.deploy` file extension.
- **Publish.html:** This file is created if you publish for web and contains launch and install link in page. `Lunch` is a link to application manifest file and `Install` is a link to setup.exe.
- **Prerequisite Installers:** You may also have some other folders like `dotnetfx45` or `reportviewer` or other prerequisite isntallers.

Here is the result of a publish on file system:

[image]

To run or install the application, click on `Sample.UI.application`.

Comment: If I run `MyProgramName.application` on very first time with the program files on same directory, does it install the program using the local files on machine or download them? and which one`MyProgramName.application` must I run, the one from root directory or from `app.publish` folder?

Comment: If you depoly on filesystem, it uses the files in `Application Files` folder. But if you deploy on a server and the user click on `lunch` link, it first download `YourProgramName.application` then it downloads `Setup.exe` and then it result in download and install `Application Files`.

Comment: You should run the `MyProgramName.application` in the root.

Comment: Sorry for being that nb.. I run this file and get an installation failure. On log, I found this information about the error http://pastebin.com/E96Vg97V (message translated by me, the real error messages aren't in English) the `ico.ico` file is both on the server and local folders within the  Application Files why I'm getting this error? What am I missing?

Comment: I Only can guess you have not included those files in your deployment because the error message doesn't point to  the address that we expect. Open your project `Properties` an go to `Publish` tab, click on `Application Files` in dialog check `Show all files` and make sure you have included required files like the one in the error message.

Comment: By the way, I think this is worth to be a separate question. And this way it will be more useful for other users :)

Comment: Just checked, this file is in there http://prntscr.com/8zeho4 I don't get why is this file path pointing to the root directory and not to the application files folder? maybe it's related to the error?

Comment: Good idea, And let me know the address of the other thread and I'll help you if I can :)

Comment: Here's the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33553386/clickonce-fails-to-download-file I ran out of ideas what's the possible reason of the error