# Clickonce fails to download file

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, deployment, clickonce

When I run myApp.application I get an installation failure. From the log error file I get this:

```
    + download error file:///C:/Users/userj/Documents/Visual Studio 2013/Projects/foo/foo/bin/x86/Release/ico.ico.deploy.
    + that the file or folder can't be found.  'C:\Users\userj\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\foo\foo\bin\x86\Release\ico.ico.deploy'.
    + that the file or folder can't be found.  'C:\Users\userj\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\foo\foo\bin\x86\Release\ico.ico.deploy'.
    + that the file or folder can't be found.  'C:\Users\userj\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\foo\foo\bin\x86\Release\ico.ico.deploy'.
```

the `ico.ico` file is both on the server and local folders within the `Application Files` folder. So why I'm getting this error? What am I missing?

**EDIT:**

Why is clickonce expecting to found a .deploy file on root directory rather than `Application Files` folder?

Comment: **1-** Is this an installation error or application execution error? Can you surely say the application installation fails? **2-** Let me know how do you add `ico.ico` to your project and where the file is located?

Comment: It's an installation error, I double-click the .application file, then click isntall and get a error saying not all files needed to download are available, so I click in details and get error messages saying about that ico.ico that can't be found

Comment: Didn't see your edit. The ico.ico file is located in the root folder together with all the .cs/.resx files of the application. I can see it on the VS solution explorer. `copy to output directory' was set to` `copy always`

Comment: And is it an embedded resource or what is the build action of that file? (I want to try to reproduce the problem)

Comment: I'm not sure I can say the application installation fails. It didn't install or run the application but the files on `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0` are created

Comment: it's an emedded resource, I added by menu properies -> applicaiton -> icon and manifest > selected the ico.ico

Comment: I must run the `.application` from root directory and not from `app.publish`, right? cause the one from `app.publish` did worked

Comment: Download the files was need in the very first time I run the `.application` file I'd like to installan using local files and downlaod new ones only if there's a more recent version of that file

Comment: Where is `app.publish`? I can't see such standard directory.

Comment: It's created automatically when I deploy the application using clickonce

Comment: it contains the files http://pastebin.com/SY09eJmL inside the `application files` folder has a folder name with the name of my app plus version with all the `.deploy` files

Comment: It doesn't create anything automatically, it's the directory name that you set as output directory for your publish and as I see, you are publishing for web!

Comment: Yes, I did publish to web via a ftp server. What I want to is: the user run the .application, if there's an update, clickonce download it otherwise start the application normally. But in the very first time I run the application it does download all the application files rather than use the local ones

Comment: Anyway It's not the reason for the problem.

Comment: But What is that `foo.exe`?

Comment: It's a copy of my application. I didn't create the `app.publish` (nor chose that name, it's probably the default) folder nor put that exe file in there. It has all been done by the VS publish wizard process

Comment: Try to publish in a clean new folder. As I know, there should not be a `foo.exe` and also I suspect that that `foo.application` probably is the wrong one.

Comment: You can choose the publish folder yourself in `Publish Location -> Publish Folder Location`  or in wizard.

Comment: I've tried it several times. The `foo.application` from root directory does't works and give the error as in the post but the one from `app.publish` does but download the files in the very first run, rather than use local ones.

Comment: I think when you say from root directory you mean app.publish folder is your root directory. Am I wrong?

Comment: That folder in `Publish Location -> Publish Folder Location` is the ftp server, I set it to `ftp://username@myserver.com/public_html/download/`

Comment: No, I mean `\bin\x86\Release`.  The folder is `app.publish` inside the ``\bin\x86\Release` folder. There are two `foo.application` files one in the `\bin\x86\Release` and another in `app.publish`. The one from root fails to run (as described in the topic) and the one from `app.publish` actually run successfully but download the fiels rather than use the local ones

Comment: Reviewing all comments, Just know I understood what you mean by `Root` directory and `app.publish` directory and when I said you should run the file `foo.application` from root directory, I mean the file under `app.publish` and not the file under the sub directory of `Application Files`

Comment: haha, sorry for the cofunsing. But about the other question, can make the clickonce install the file using the local ones rather than download them in the very first time that I run it? it's even possible? I selected the application is avialble either online or offlien for that

Comment: Nevermind, I did notice it isn't download from server but a local folder.

Comment: The thing that I was sure about and wondered how it is downloading from server!

Comment: When you publish an application you should install/run the application using `YourApp.application` from your publish folder. If you run the `YourApp.application` that is located in your debug/release folder, you will receive such error.

Comment: I'm going to post it as answer. maybe it helps to future readers and prevent 2 hours test and chat ;)

Comment: Thanks. Sure, do it so I'll accept. Sorry if I did wast your time anyway

Comment: It wan not waste of time at all! it was a good experience based on a misunderstanding ;)

Comment: haha, sure it was :) but why is that .application copy put in that directory, after all? to this work, it must have  the application files in same directory as well, which isn't the case

Comment: To be honest I have never noticed that files in the application directory and I always set the publishing folder location and use files there :)

Comment: Thank you for your feedback to the answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you publish an application you should install/run the application using `YourApp.application` from your **publish folder**.

If you run the `YourApp.application` that is located in your **debug/release folder**, you will receive such error and if you click on `Detail` button of error dialog you will see the log file containing some errors including those you post in the question.

[image]